# Why does the JSF action tag handler in JSP invoke rendering immediately after creation?

Tags: jsp, jsf, facelets

I read the article ["Improving JSF by Dumping JSP"](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/06/09/jsf.html?page=1) from Hans Bergsten.

There I read the following:

> The JSP container processes the page and invokes the JSF action tag handlers as they are encountered. A JSF tag handler looks for the JSF component it represents in the component tree. If it can't find the component, it creates it and adds it to the component tree. **It then asks the component to render itself**.

and furthermore

> On the first request, the `<h:outputLabel>` action creates its component **and asks it to render itself**.

I understand that the immediate rendering after the creation of the component is the problem here (The reference to the input component can't be resolved in the example). That's one point, why JSF doesn't fit with JSP.

But it reads as if the action tag handler itself would ask the component to render. Or is it JSP that triggers the rendering directly after the action tag handler created the component.

**If it is the action tag handler, I don't understand, why this is the fault of JSP.**
What is different here than from JSF intended?